# Is it possible to use geolocation without asking user permissions?

Tags: geolocation

I have read all the posts relating to this probelm, but none of them seem to match my request close enough to help me.

I have a weather widget on a website which uses geolocation to determine the location, is it possible to automatically grant permission without the user being asked for permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to the browser to determine whether to provide geolocation information (in the HTML5 sense; after all, you can already determine limited data from their IP address). Whilst there may be some browsers that provide the information silently, none of the mainstream ones default to this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, I had assumed that, just was hoping there was a way, the client doesn't want it, all well, I'll let him know. Thanks